# Sequence of complex numbers for which sine blows up

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, limits

Construct a sequence of complex numbers $(z_n)_{n \geq 1}$ such that $\sin z_n$ is real for all $n$ and $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sin{z_n}=\infty$$.
Or give a proof that there exist no such sequence.

Comment: $\sin z_n$ has to be real.

Comment: ...but $z_n$ does not have to be real.

Comment: It could be a real number or a complex number where the real part is an odd multiple of $\frac{\pi}{2}$. This follows since $\sin(a+b\iota)=\sin a \cosh b + \iota \cos a \sinh b$

Comment: It seems like you're on the right track. Why not make the real part of $z_n$ fixed and have the imaginary part go to infinity as $n\to\infty$?

Comment: Got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just solve the equation $\sin (z_n)=n$. If $w=e^{iz_n}$ this equation becomes $w-\frac 1 w =2ni$ or $w^{2}-2niw-1=0$. You have to solve this quadratic and then take logarithm. (There are infinitely many choices for $z_n$!).